# Ensure a method only fires once when an event is triggered multiple times in Winforms newer method in .NET 4.5

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.5

So essentially I have wired up three text boxes to do a smart filter and want to let a user do a multi filter.  The only problem was that it was firing too frequently and I want to have it fire after a delay.  The event for 'TextChanged' is wired up to basically run and I have a simplified example of what I want:

I have a simple Winforms UI with two text boxes: "txtWait" and "txtTest".  In the front end code the properties are default and the text are:

```
txtWait.Text = 1000
txtTest.Text = "Test Text I have here to look at"
```

A way to test this is to just hit the backspace a few times and wait.  I would want only the last text to show once.  I just got this part to work but the resetting it not occurring as I would expect.  I would expect a person could hit backspace, backspace, (only a half a second had passed), backspace(clock resets and new wait begins).

And my code behind is:

```
Public Class DelayBeforeAction

  Private _loaded As Boolean = False
  Private _sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    _loaded = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub txtTest_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtTest.TextChanged
    If _loaded Then
      _sw.Start()

      DelayExecute(Sub() If _sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > CInt(txtWait.Text) Then _sw.Reset() : MessageBox.Show(txtTest.Text) Else _sw.Reset(), CInt(txtWait.Text))
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Async Sub DelayExecute(action As Action, timeout As Integer)
    Await Task.Delay(timeout)
    action()
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I should add I did add a C# tag that was removed in meaning I would accept a C# answer as well.  I am fine with doing code in C# or VB.Net.

Comment: If you used a button the user pressed to indicate "I am done setting the criteria"  you dont need to delay.  Especially if there will be multiple textboxes

Comment: @Plutonix Yes and that is a good point but I also want to know how to do it the way in the question with just event driven behavior.

Comment: Looks over-engineered, with not enough of it, async/await is not *always* the best choice.  It is dead-simple the old-fashioned way with a plain Timer from the toolbox.  Call Stop() and Start() to restart the timer, Stop() in the Leave event handler.

Comment: @Hans: The timer only has a tick event from what I can see.  What benefit would it give me the stopwatch does not already?  I do not want to leave the message box that is the whole point of my question.  Of course it is simple if I just give up what I am trying to accomplish and then just have a simple single event on leave.

Comment: @djangojazz Hans Passant does have a point. With a timer, you'd show the message box during the `Tick` event. You'd re-start the timer before that event if the user types more characters. The advantage is that when you stop the timer early, you don't need to cancel anything else, because the timer itself will already ensure no event gets raised. Whether it scales well to a more general solution for your real code is something for you to determine, but it may well.

Comment: @hvd It fires multiple times and is blocking appears to be the problem.  Even if I do a timer.Stop() then another line timer.Start().  When I handle the timer.Tick event with MessageBox.Show(txtTest.Text) then timer.Stop(), it shows up multiple times.   The whole reason I went down the road of the async await delay was for this very reason of repeat unintended messageboxes or calls.

Comment: I in essence imagine that the code would be doing a minimal way of offloading something to a seperate context separated and it finishes the work.  I have a producer pattern working for this, but it seems like a lot of code which is why I specifically called out .NET 4.5 and was curious if someone that knew more than I did of doing it with new Task Async.  The problem with a cancellation token and setting one up is just passing one does nothing.  I tried passing in one and it does nothing so you would need to track instances I would guess, without an example it is easy to say 'simple'.

Comment: @djangojazz Heh. If you go with a timer, in the `Tick` event handler, stop the timer first, *then* show the message box. Otherwise, the timer may fire while the message box is still being displayed.

Comment: @hvd Interesting, that worked.  Did not think of the order of operation properly.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Concretely in your case, your first `txtTest_TextChanged` starts a stopwatch. Your second `txtTest_TextChanged` calls `_sw.Start()` again, [which has no effect on a running stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Starting a Stopwatch that is already running does not change the timer state or reset the elapsed time properties.

When the first `txtTest_TextChanged`'s continuation runs, the stopwatch's elapsed time is expected to be greater than a second: it was started more than a second ago, and since then, all that happened is that other attempts were made to start the same stopwatch. Nothing was reset.

That said, using a stopwatch here is inherently unreliable and I do not recommend continuing down this path. You cannot be sure exactly when your continuation runs.

Instead, do not measure whether your continuation should probably be cancelled, *track* whether it *was* cancelled.

The most direct way in your particular case would be to increment a counter in `txtTest_TextChanged`. If the counter has not been changed by the time the continuation is executed, you know `txtTest_TextChanged` hasn't been called a second time.

A more general way is to use the [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Most task-based methods, including [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194865(v=vs.110).aspx), have overloads accepting `CancellationToken` instances. You can indicate a request for cancellation through [`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955(v=vs.110).aspx).

Although you do not need it in this case, in general, you can also call [`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) explicitly in specific locations during long-running operations that would not otherwise be aborted.

Comment: How would you identify with a counter when to use it if it is always increment?  You need a reference to what it needs to be.  If I just get 1 then 2 then 3 how do I know what number to use and when?  The reason for a timer I did was for this precise reason to know when a second had passed to attempt.  I do agree that it is unreliable as it never seems to restart properly in the async action.  The cancellation method I went down but without a specific example usage just adding a cancellation token on the overload of Task.Delay does nothing.

Comment: @djangojazz The basic idea of the counter is simply `++this.Counter; var captured = this.Counter; DelayExecute(() => { if (this.Counter != captured) return; ... });`. For the cancellation, did you actually call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` on the original `CancellationTokenSource` that provided the `CancellationToken` you passed to `Task.Delay`? That *should* have an effect. Had you commented it wasn't enough, I might have an idea, but I don't have ideas why it wouldn't work at all. That's the whole point of that overload.